# Three-phase thyristor rectifier - Minimum firing angle

Tags: power-electronics, control-system, electricity, thyristor

Why is a minimum firing angle (>0, usually 5-15°) defined for three-phase thyristor rectifier?

I would like a technical explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The minimum firing angle for a three-phase thyristor is 30 degree. Below thirty degrees the thyristor is already reverse biased by the third thyristor that is already conducting. Let's understand the waveform:
[image: Minimum firing angle of three-phase thyristor]

If the minimum firing angle is less than 30, the circuit operates in continuous conduction mode instead.

Comment: Hi, To comply with the [rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) about referencing material from elsewhere, can you please edit the answer & add a link to that image (or reference the book title & author, if it came from a book)? Thanks. (I'll delete this comment after the reference is added, to avoid clutter.)